# validate entire form using $asyncValidators

Tags: angularjs, rest, angularjs-directive

is it possible to validate an entire form instead of the individual fields of the form? I have a REST api that I would like to receive validation errors from but all the examples that I have come across are attaching a directive to individual fields instead of the form tag.